# Using geolocation inside angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, geolocation

I've found that you have to use what I think is a workaround to get the geolocation data from the browser API. My question is why can't this be accessed the normal way when I can see the output data in the console log?

For example, in this case the lat and long are output, but the "mapoutput" is never updated:

```
function get_location() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(show_map);
  console.log('nav: ', navigator);
}

function show_map(position) {
  var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

  self.mapoutput = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&zoom=13&size=300x300&sensor=false";
  console.log("latitude: ", latitude);
  console.log("longitude: ", longitude);
}

get_location();
```

I thought the show_map WAS the asynchronous callback, so why isn't self.mapoutput updated properly?

Comment: Angular only updates data bindings when `$digest` is run. Did you try wrapping your assignment in a call to [`$apply`](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)?

Comment: Ok, thanks I added this: $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.mapoutput = "blahstringpositionhere";      });

And got it to work. So this triggers the digest method which updates? Why is this required for this particular scenario? Pretty much the same for trying to update via jquery/documentid isn't it? Feel free to re-post the code as an answer so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular only updates data bindings when `$digest` is run. For callbacks set up through Angular functions, this is already done by Angular code. If you go outside of Angular you must do this yourself by wrapping the body of your callback in a call to [`$apply`](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html).